# Resizable page inside a frame

Tags: c#, wpf, frame, resizable

I'm building a navigation based application in WPF. I have a main window which contains some tabs. Each tab contains a frame in which the associated page shall be shown.

I want my page (and its controls) to be resized when I change the size of the main window. I tried settings margins and not setting width and height, but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you share a sample code which illustrates your problem?

Comment: I was making a huge mistake! I was setting page's Width Height instead of just setting d:DesignHeight and d:DesignWidth. Should I delete my question now?

Comment: Maybe answer your own question, or just delete it. Your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see my mistake now. To have a resizable page, you should just set d:DesignHeight and d:DesignWidth, not Height and Width themselves.